# Run JavaScript block depending on ViewBag value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, viewbag

I am trying to run a piece of JavaScript code, but only if a ViewBag value is equal to null. Below is a example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var defDate = @ViewBag.EndDate;
    if (defDate == null)
    {
        $('#dt2').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'en-GB',
            format: 'L',
            showClear: true
        });
    }

    else
    {
        $('#dt2').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: defDate,
            locale: 'en-GB',
            format: 'L',
            showClear: true
        });
    }

</script>
```

However, this doesn't appear to be working, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I think I have both of these JavaScript blocks to run on start? Should I be making a separate one which runs on start and then runs the relevant (non-starting) function - if that makes sense?

Here is where the ViewBag is initialised as requested:

```
ViewBag.EndDate = endDateFilter;
```

Comment: First try to put your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){`. Second, could you post code where initialize `ViewBag.EndDate`, please?

Comment: @erikscandola I'll add it to the post, but this should matter at all, just assume its either null or it has a value.

Comment: But if value is a string you need to add quotes: `"@ViewBag.EndDate"`. If value is a `DateTime` the solution is not the same.

Comment: Sorry I understand, it is parsed as a string, like Felix Cen's answer which worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Yes, Felix's answer is right if you have a string even if you always initialize `endDateFilter`. If `endDateFilter` was not initilize in your javascript you will have `var defDate = "null";` and the if will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the viewbag value in quotes. Try the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var defDate = '@ViewBag.EndDate';
        if (defDate == '')
        {
            $('#dt2').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'en-GB',
                format: 'L',
                showClear: true
            });
        }

        else
        {
            $('#dt2').datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: defDate,
                locale: 'en-GB',
                format: 'L',
                showClear: true
            });
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Much appreciated - thought I was close, just shows my lack of JS knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
(defDate == null)
```

with

```
(defDate.length < 1)
```

Comment: Hi, tried this, still didn't work, the datepicker won't open.